# Does this means the python path for pip install is incorrect? If so, how do I know the right path and then how do I change that?

Tags: python, powershell, path, pip, installation

I am trying to pip install Jupyter but powershell is giving me this error:

```
C:\Users\me> pip install jupyter
pip : The term 'pip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included,
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ pip install jupyter
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pip:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I have tried reading other questions on here about fixing paths, but those solutions did not work correctly for me even after re-booting powershell and my system. Also, I performed both a system update and re-installed python. None of that worked.

Comment: Have you installed `pip` successfully? And did you add `pip` to PATH environment variable? maybe you can try to use `pip3`...

Answer (score 0):

I've found that if python is not on your path then pip doesn't work. Run the command below to see what you have on your path.

`PS> ($env:PATH).split(';')`

If you don't see python on the path then add it like I have below (assuming your python install is in a directory named `python` in `c:\`.

`PS> $env:PATH = "$($env:PATH);C:\python"`

Try running pip in the same PowerShell console as the previous two commands. If it works, then you'll need to add `c:\python` to your PATH permanently.